# Escape jekyll liquid tags

Tags: templates, jekyll, liquid

This sounds very easy, however I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs. How can I write @site in a post code in jekyll, without it being processed by the engine?

It is being converted to https://github.com/site' class='user-mention'>https://github.com/site' class='user-mention'>@site

Comment: It is due to jekyll-mentions plugin.Removing that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in  {%raw%} and {%endraw%}.

Comment: I already wrapped the code in raw tags. It is my own mistake,I have jekyll-mentions plugin which is converting all @tags to github user mentions.